# Apache Tomcat use XAMPP MySQL Database

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, jdbc, xampp

I have installed Tomcat 6 and apache XAMPP on MAC OS. XAMPP includes MySQL.

I turn on TOMCAT and XAMPP.

Then i try to connect with JDBC to MySQL.

```
public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Connection conn = null;
        try
        {
            String userName = "root";
            String password = "";
            //<facility> is the name of the database i created
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/facility"; 
            Class.forName ("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance ();
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection (url, userName, password);
            System.out.println ("Database connection established");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println ("Cannot connect to database server");
        }

        finally
        {
            if (conn != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    conn.close ();
                    System.out.println ("Database connection terminated");
                }
                catch (Exception e) { /* ignore close errors */ }
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Well it gives me back "Cannot connect to database server".

Comment: Is it possible to interact XAMPP with TOMCAT without any further configuration. In my example i get an exception that connection failed.

Comment: Can the phpMyAdmin in xampp connect with mysql?

Comment: print the exception and read the message: System.out.println ("Cannot connect to database server "  + e.getMessage());

Comment: Yes it can. With phpMyAdmin i created the "facility" database

Comment: Ok this is the message: Cannot connect to database server com.mysql.jdbc.Driver. Ela Costi apo thn Criti, voi8a ligo re kopeli :P

Comment: Can you also print the exception type e.getClass().getName()? I'm thinking it might not be able to find/load the driver.

Comment: Eelke thats the output: Cannot connect to database server java.lang.ClassNotFoundException. How can it find the driver? Please post it as an answer to vote up :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is at the JDBC driver. You must include it to your classpath.

You download it here: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.0.html

Add the mysql-connector-java-5.1.15-bin.jar to your classpath

Then it will work.